# Separate parameters for Date and Time

Tags: ssrs-2008

I want to use one parameter for date and another one for time in my reports as shown below.
Start Time `[16/01/2012][12.00 am]`

Can anyone help me regarding that?

Comment: Can you ellaborate? You want to have two fields on your report or passed as parameters?

Comment: I want to use two parameters 1st for Date and 2nd one for Time. I will not use any Dataset for the parameters. For date it is like calender and Time it is like 00.00, 01.00,02.00 etc. And also want to hide the time parameter label. Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I'll add an answer so you can see your options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is a multiple step process:

1. Set up a variable of TEXT as 'DATE' as the variable value and prompt
2. Set it's 'Default Values' in the left pane to be '1/16/2012'
3. Set up a variable of TEXT as 'TIME' as the variable value and prompt
4. Set it's 'Default Values' in the left pane to be '00:00'
5. Set up a dataset, 'AvailableDateTime' to combine the two into a legitimate datetime field:

   ```
   SELECT        CAST(@Date + ' ' + @Time AS DateTime) AS Datetime
   ```
6. Set up a third variable of DATETIME to be 'DATETIME' as the variable value and prompt.
7. Set up this variable to use 'AVAILABLE VALUES' on the left pane of properties to be 'Get values from a query'.  Use the dataset from step 5.

You now have set up a separate field for data and time.

Further consideration to avoid user input error.  You may wish to tie the first variables to be selectable ONLY FROM values you set in available values or from a query.  The problem being if a user fat fingers the date or time it will not run as the system is only trying to combine two strings and make a datetime out of it.  You may wish to list values directly from a query from the getgo.

EDIT FOR CHANGING FIRST TWO VARIABLES:

1. You may set the first variable as datetime which gives the end user a calendar.
2. You can set a second dataset up to get available times for an end user:

   ```
   declare @time table ( tm int)

   declare @cursor int = 0

   while @cursor <= 23
   Begin
       insert into @time values (@cursor)

       set @cursor += 1
   End

   select cast(CAST(tm as varchar) + ':00' as time) as HourOfTheDay
   from @time
   ```
3. Setting your second variable to get values from a query that is made in step 2 directly above.

You should now be able to put the values together as above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But I want to take treat the parameters as date time picker.There will be no dataset for that parameters. How it is possible then?

Comment: Just set the data types differently for the first two choices and choose them.  Set the first one as datetime and it will apply a calendar then.  Set the second one as text or int and you may validate the numbers first if you want.  You could set a while loop in SQL to select all the possible hours and then bind to that.  You bind a variable with the left pane stating 'Available values'>'Get values from query'.  I will update my example to give you info.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, `SSRS` does not allow you to have separate parameters for `Date` and `Time`.
It has only one parameter `Date/Time`.

As I see you have two options.

1. Add a text parameter and consider that as time. You could then do
   some validation depending on what tech you are using.
2. Another way to solve this would be creating a list of possible
   values. You select `Integer` type, for instance and then create a list
   of `Available Values`. (see images)

[image]

[image]