# SRSS Input Parameter Date/time as a time parameter without date

Tags: reporting-services

I found hundreds of articles, how can i exclude the time part of an date/time - Parameter. But i need just the time part from the date/time parameter. I don't know if the parameter is the best way because it present a calendar picker. That's not helpful i you want to select a specific time. But I also don't want offer dropdown fields for hours and minutes. 
The best way in my opinion is a preformated field with HH:mm and in best case the colon is not removeable. How do you manage this usually? Do you use a input parameter as type text or do you found the needed statement?

thanks
Frank

Comment: As far as i understood your question, you want only date as a parameter & not the time present with date. So, if this is your question, answer is do it in the DataSet like datpart(date,thedate) or may be you can find date functions in expression part in SSRS.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I'm looking for the other side. I want only the time without the datepart as input parameter for the reportgeneration. BR Frank

Comment: Hi Frank. You want only time as a prameter in such a way that, in one text box, you want, [hour]:[minute] which should be entered by user. Possibly its not possible. what we can do is, use one text box for [Hour] & one for [Minute]. Please go through these links, might help you out. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134334/ssrs-date-time-picker-allow-user-to-pick-the-time-component]      [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437475/separate-parameters-for-date-and-time]